# How to monitor Ceph OSD object access?

Tags: ceph

I have setup a Ceph object storage cluster, and I want to monitor the object's access behavior on each OSD. For example, when the object is written to this OSD? How large it is? How long it takes?

So are there any tools or APIs could help me build such a monitor?

Answer (score 1):

For a particular object that exists, you can setup a client to watch the object, and recieve notification about changes. From there you could issue a stat.

https://github.com/ceph/ceph/blob/master/src/include/rados/librados.hpp#L709

Comment: Thanks Noah for your reply, but I am sure if I could associate the object's changes with specific OSD?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I mean through the watch-notification method, can I know which OSD operate the object? Or can I write a small monitor on each OSD to track the operate of each OSD, e.g. read/write an object?

Comment: Once you are notified that an object has changed, you can look-up its location, which will tell you the primary OSD and its replicas that store the object.